# Furnace relay - old one says 18 LRA, replacement says 48 LRA - Does it matter?

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace, air-conditioning, relay

forgive me if this is a newbie question. I am replacing a relay inside an electrical furnace/air handler. It is a relay model 90-293Q. The original one I have specifies it as "8 FLA, *18* LRA" but the replacement model (same model number) specifies it as "8 FLA, *48* LRA". I Googled around a bit but the best I could come up with is what it stands for (Locked Rotor Amps) without finding any info on whether or not having more LRA on a relay will matter. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LRA is simply the maximum amperage the relay is rated for when starting up a motor. Having a higher LRA just means you have a higher rated relay for starting currents. Having more will not matter.
The FLA or full load amperage is the rated operating amperage which in your case is the same as the original.

In many cases it's easier to just make a higher rated relay and use it for many different applications.